# How to display blank if linked cell is blank? Excel 2010

Tags: microsoft-excel, worksheet-function

I have a database that have two sheets, Sheet 1 is a link of Sheet 2. if a cell in Sheet 2 is blank then I want the same cells in Sheet 1 to be blank, instead they either show "0" or "00/01/1900" how do I stop this?

Comment: What do you mean by linked? By a formula / pivot table / ...? If it's a formula, then instead of `=Sheet1!A1` write `=IF(Sheet1!A1="","",Sheet1!A1)`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Simply add an IF statement to the mix.

Lets assume that the formula in your cell is `=A1` and you want to make sure it doesn't display anything if the cell is empty, change the formula accordingly:

```
=IF(ISBLANK(A1);"";A1)
```

I use the formula ISBLANK. If its true, return "", if it isn't, then return whatever it is.

Of course, you would need to replace A1 with the actual formula, which links to your other workbook. Don't forget that you have to type it twice. Once for the check, and once for the result.

If you have many cells and you want a quick and dirty way, consider using Conditional Formatting. Select all cells, And go to menu data->Conditional Formatting. In the formula specify if empty, and then simply paint everything white.