# Nested IF Formula Not Returning Correctly

Tags: microsoft-excel

Excel Formula Help:

```
=IF(K3,"","",IF(K3>=0,AVERAGE(K3:K6)))
```

If a cell is blank, I want it to return blank, but if it has data, I want it to average a series of data.

Comment: the first part should be`K3=""`, not `K3,""`

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to display blank if linked cell is blank? Excel 2010](https://superuser.com/questions/1210855/how-to-display-blank-if-linked-cell-is-blank-excel-2010)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What you want to use is `ISBLANK`, not `""`

```
=IF(ISBLANK(K3),"",IF(K3>=0,AVERAGE(K3:K6),""))
```

Here's a picture of it in my sheet:

[image]

Comment: Good one you get +10 ☺

Comment: Nicely demonstrated. Here's another +10 for you :)

Comment: Thank you so much!!  I was able to enter it the way you suggested and it worked great!  Such a relief.